# Function reference retrieved from table won't accept any arguments

Tags: lua

I have a table of function references as follows:

```
KLC.ChatCommandBank = {
test = KLC.TestFunction,
config = KLC.OpenInterfaceOptions,
option = KLC.OpenInterfaceOptions,
options = KLC.OpenInterfaceOptions,
help = KLC.PrintHelp
};
```

but when `f = "test"` and `t` is a table of strings and I call

```
KLC.ChatCommandBank[f](t);
```

then the function

```
function KLC:TestFunction(tab)
    print(tab);
end
```

has a `nil` value for `tab`, despite the fact that when the function is called, `t` is not `nil`.

I suspect this is due to the table of function references not having arguments defined; I haven't been able to find anything with a google and my own tinkering couldn't fix it! Any input appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you *define* function as `KLC:TestFunction(tab)` it gets one implicit parameter `self` that refers to the table it's called on.

When you call it as `KLC.ChatCommandBank[f](t)`, you need to explicitly pass something in place of that parameter:

```
KLC.ChatCommandBank[f](KLC, t)
```

Alternatively, you can change the definition to `local function KLC.TestFunction(tab)`.